# Google Glass Timeline Item with NAVIGATE action is not showing up on Glass device

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Why doesn't a timeline item with this payload offer the turn by turn navigation options from Google Glass, is there a bug ? If the answer is because it needs more properties set that sucks to make us call another endpoint.

```
{
  "kind": "mirror#timelineItem",
  "id": "035cb808-a908-4057-914f-f980fb35c620",
  "bundleId": "12",
  "created": "2013-08-21T22:52:54.635Z",
  "updated": "2013-08-21T22:52:54.635Z",
  "etag": "\"hzfI85yu0lKQdtWV4PO1jAbQxWw/UvNo_kKkfbIjHfhmNjOLyMSNIeA\"",
  "creator": {
    "kind": "mirror#contact",
    "source": "api:34091916267",
    "id": "70",
    "displayName": "Monica Wilkinson"
  },
  "title": "glass-4",
  "text": "...",
  "html": "....",
  "speakableText": "...",
  "location": {
    "kind": "mirror#location",
    "latitude": 37.7657774,
    "longitude": -122.4075774,
    "displayName": "Crushpath Labs"
  },
  "menuItems": [
    {
      "action": "NAVIGATE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What response are you getting when you insert this item?

Comment: Jenny & Clocker this is the response I get when I insert. Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you using the client library? I think you may have to add more params to the location resource and menuItems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
"location": {
    "latitude": 37.7657774,
    "longitude": -122.4075774,
    "accuracy": 36.0
  },

It works for me.